# Как создать счётчик файлов на js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть книги в формате pdf в папке bin.

И я решил добавить фичу - счётчик количества тех самых книг, который выводился б на сайте через html тег.

Я знаю, что js ограничен возможностями работы с файлами, но есть ли способ?

Например:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вообще в таких случаях используют серверный язык и запрашивают количество записей о файлах из бд, потом его просто отображают. Если вы не владеете серверным языком программирования, а хотите реализовать только на js,то это в принципе странно немного.

Comment: @navasiolau, странны ваши речи - из них следует что JS не серверный язык

Comment: @qwabra в целом ничего не мешает использовать js на серверной стороне, но он не для этого был сделан изначально и лично я не использовал его на сервере, поэтому и советов по его серверному использованию не даю =)

Comment: @YaroslavKutsela, "выводился б на сайте" - а сайт а чём написан ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На англоязычном стэке обнаружил такое решение на чистом js

```
var fs = require('fs');

function sortDirectory(path, files, callback, i, dir) {
    if (!i) {i = 0;}                                            //Init
    if (!dir) {dir = [];}
    if(i < files.length) {                                      //For all files
        fs.lstat(path + '\\' + files[i], function (err, stat) { //Get stats of the file
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            if(stat.isDirectory()) {                            //Check if directory
                dir.push(files[i]);                             //If so, ad it to the list
            }
            sortDirectory(callback, i + 1, dir);                //Iterate
        });
    } else {
        callback(dir);                                          //Once all files have been tested, return
    }
}

function listDirectory(path, callback) {
    fs.readdir(path, function (err, files) {                    //List all files in the target directory
        if(err) {
            callback(err);                                      //Abort if error
        } else {
            sortDirectory(path, files, function (dir) {         //Get only directory
                callback(dir);
            });
        }
    })
}

listDirectory('C:\\My\\Test\\Directory', function (dir) {
    console.log('There is ' + dir.length + ' directories: ' + dir);
});
```

Ознакомьтесь сами с той мемой по этой [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775113/count-the-number-of-files-in-a-directory-using-javascript-nodejs)

Comment: КАК МИНИМУМ вы забыли в ответе упомянуть NodeJS

Answer (score 0):

js не ограничен, это просто язык. Ограничена программа на js в браузере.

Вам нужна программа на любом языке (хоть на js), которая будет запускаться там, где лежат книги, и считать их.

Одно из:

- программа-сервер, который будет делать это по запросу из браузера и отдавать браузеру
- программа-генератор, который будет запускаться руками, периодичаски или еще как-то, и записывать статический html туда, откуда простой сервер будет отдавать браузеру

---

примеры серверных технологий: js/nodejs, php, python/flask, java/jetty